# How to upload a file using Quickbase API in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbase

I'm using the [Quickbase C# SDK](https://github.com/QuickbaseAdmirer/QuickBase-C-Sharp-SDK) to submit a form to Quickbase from an external site. I want to attach a file along with the form and can't seem to figure out how to do so.

Below is a stripped version of my code:

ASPX

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFileName" CssClass="textbox" Columns="40" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="file" id="attachment1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

CS

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IQClient client = QuickBase.Login("username", "password", "domain"); 
    IQApplication app = client.Connect("db_id", "app_token";
    AppInfo appInfo = app.GetApplicationInfo();
    IQTable table = app.GetTable("table_id");

    IQRecord newRecord = table.NewRecord();
    newRecord["File Name"] = txtFileName.Text;
    // attach file?
    newRecord.AcceptChanges();
    table.AcceptChanges();
    client.Logout();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I'd figure out my own question after submitting it to StackOverflow. Of course.

But I'll post my solution just in case other people are having the same problem.

I had to add a function to [QuickBase C# SDK](https://github.com/QuickbaseAdmirer/QuickBase-C-Sharp-SDK) and recompile the DLL to get this to work.

Add this line to IQRecord.cs:

```
void UploadFile(string columnName, string filePath);
```

Add this function to QRecord.cs:

```
public void UploadFile(string columnName, string filePath)
{
    // create new field with columnName
    var index = GetColumnIndex(columnName);
    CreateNewField(index, columnName);

    // change field type to file
    Columns[index].ColumnType = FieldType.file;

    // Get field location with column index
    var fieldIndex = _fields.IndexOf(new QField(Columns[index].ColumnId));
    SetExistingField(index, fieldIndex, filePath);
}
```

Compile and use like so:

```
// code to upload file to temporary location
newRecord.UploadFile("Story", "path_to_temporary_location");
// delete temporary file
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this post!  I did not need to upload a file, I just needed to know how to add a new record to a Quickbase table, and your post showed me how.